was/were reluctant to-infinitive (implication)

Maddox was reluctant to talk about it.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/reluctant
Does this sentence imply that Maddox did not talk about it?
An English-Japanese dictionary says that "She was unwilling to give any information" implies that she did not give any information, but Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says that "reluctant" means "slow and unwilling". I am totally confused.

Have you never done something that you were reluctant to do?

Many conscripts are reluctant to go to war even as they are  on their way to the front.  Cattle can be reluctant to enter a pen even as they are being herded into it.

@MichaelHarvey I've edited my post. You seem to think that what is obvious to native English speakers is obvious to Japanese learners of English. Note that I am not a native speaker of a Western language and Japanese has little in common with English. It's a shame that my favorite English language forum has stopped working.

To be unwilling to do something can mean either to refuse to do it or to do it  reluctantly (that is, wishing you didn't have to). I imagine 'Maddox' being encouraged to talk and finally saying a few grudging words.

The answer depends on the nature of verb's action and the tense of the verb.  If the action is a one-time event that cannot be undone, then to say that someone is reluctant implies that they have not yet done the action:

Maddox is reluctant to jump across the patch of quicksand.

But if the verb is one whose action is ongoing, the person can be in the midst of doing the action and still be reluctant to continue doing it:

Maddox is reluctant to speak and is not being very forthcoming with information about the heist.


Many conscripts are reluctant to fight even as they are firing their weapons.

However, once we change to the  past tense, then there's no way to know if the action was ever undertaken:

Maddox was reluctant to jump.

Maddox might have refused to jump or he might have jumped.

Many of the conscripts were reluctant to fight.

The conscripts might have deserted or they might have fought in a battle.
